# Combining history, tail and sed commands in Shell

Tags: shell

I am new to Unix shell scripting and having a hard time understanding this below piece of code.

```
TASK_DETAIL=$(echo `history |tail -n1 |head -n1` | sed 's/[0-9]* //')
```

I haven't come across `-n1` in any documentation. So I am confused.

I would very much appreciate it if anyone threw some light on this.

Comment: Well, `... | tail -n1 | head -n1` is the same as `... | tail -n1` as you are printing the last `1` line of whatever comes before. There is no need to also `head` `1` line -- as `1 = 1`. You probably meant `$(history | tail -nX)` for the last `X` lines in the history file, or `$(history | head -nX)` for the first `X` lines, or `$(history | tail -nX | head -nY)` for the first `Y` lines of the last `X` in the history file (where `X > Y`). (**note:** you do not `echo history`, just `history` to invoke the `history` command.)

Comment: use your "local" documentation `man head ; man tail` to see specifics of your version, rather than rely on google searches. When you post code, also useful to mention the OS version (and release name if there is one). Finally learn to debug such constructs by executing parts of the whole, adding a command segment after each pipe as you understand what is happening in the earlier code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -n1` is the same as `tail -1` :)